# How word embeddings work for word similarity?

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding, doc2vec

I am trying to apply word2vec/doc2vec to find similar sentences. First consider word2vec for word similarity. What I understand is, CBOW can be used to find most suitable word given a context, whereas Skip-gram is used to find the context given some word, so in both cases, I am getting words that co-occur frequently. But how does it work to find similar words? My intuition is, since similar words tend to occur in similar contexts, the words similarity is actually measured from the similarity among contextual/co-occuring words. In the neural net, when the vector representation for some word at the hidden layer is passed through to the output layer, it outputs probabilities of co-occuring words. So, the co-occuring words influence the vectors of some words, and since similar words have similar set of co-occuring words, their vector representations are also similar. To find the similarity, we need to extract the hidden layer weights (or vectors) for each word and measure their similarities. Do I understand it correctly?

Finally, what is a good way to find tweet text (full sentence) similarity using word2vec/doc2vec?

Comment: Maybe better migrate to [DataScience.SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this is a question for Stack Overflow but here goes my attempt at a reply...

You have the basic notions right, though you're mixing the definition of the goal with the implementation when you mention neural nets, there are other ways to get at word embedding for CBOW and skip-gram.

The word embedding can then be transferred (called transfer learning usually but in NLP they simply term it the embedding layer, which is standard practice to put as the first layer) to another domain and either kept frozen or tweaked for the more complex NLP task at hand, So...

As for your last question, it really depends on the specifics of the task

1. what are you using the tweet distance for?
2. Is it supervised or unsupervised?
3. What is the output space?

I think for unsupervised learning of doc2vec for something like clustering for topics a good bet would be to try autoencoders (see [Hinton's dimensionality reduction paper](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/science.pdf)) a language model (and taking the last hidden vector) [wmd](https://chara.cs.illinois.edu/sites/fa16-cs591txt/pdf/Kusner-2015-ICML.pdf) (I think its implemented in gensim) and many others (there are also other BOW like methods that don't use word embedding at all)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will update my question for the second part. So in summary, are you saying that whatever the implementation is, the learned vectors for words captures their context also, and they are extracted and used to find similarity based on contextual cues?

Comment: There's a saying by a famous linguist (J.R.Firth) "you shall know a word by the company it keeps" you build the vectors by trying to predict their context. A word's meaning and its context are considered to be highly related so as a by product of predicting the context you get it's meaning.

Comment: For instance if prediction in a certain language requires knowing the word's gender then presumably the representation vector space will contain some sub space containing the gender structure of the language, etc... And this makes perfect sense since a words gender is usually correlated to the gender of nearby words (adjectives, verbs (in some languages), etc...)